# means on box plots as symbols with several variables

Tags: r

I have got ten box plots:

```
 boxplot( Daten$weight~interaction(Daten$Dosis,Daten$sex, drop=TRUE))
```

and need the means in them, so I tried:

```
means<-tapply(Daten$weight, Daten$Dosis, mean)
points(means, pch=5, col="red", lwd=5)
```

but the result is, I only got the dots for means for male, what happened with female?

Answer (score 1):

In your plotting, the call to `interaction(Dosis, sex)` generates a factor with one level percombination of Dosis and sex.

You just need to include the same in your call to `tapply`:

```
# use of `with` to save typing Daten$ over and over again
means <- with(Daten, tapply(weight, interaction(Dosis, sex), mean))
```

(Note: for `boxplot` you can do `boxplot(weight ~ interaction(Dosis, sex, drop=T), dat=Daten)` to save typing all the `Daten$`)